# linq query and nulls

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I would like to query with linq some xml file. There are some required and some optional elements. Only required is name - everything else is optional.
If there is some NULL for example cageCode = NULL - it doesnt select anything - I need to add to List of strings  - "" - I tried it like below, but it doesnt work. When I have everything filled it works fine, when there is something NULL it doesnt save to list anything.
Could you help me how to set "" to list where is null element? 
Thanks!

```
var queryManufacturer = from dataManufaturer in input.Identification.Manufacturers.Manufacturer
                                                select
                                                new
                                                { 
                                                    dataManufaturer.name,
                                                    dataManufaturer.cageCode,
                                                    dataManufaturer.FaxNumber,
                                                    dataManufaturer.URL.OriginalString
                                                };

                foreach (var a in queryManufacturer)
                {
                    data.Add(a.name);
                    if (a.cageCode == null) data.Add("");
                    else data.Add(a.cageCode);
                    if (a.FaxNumber == null) data.Add("");
                    else data.Add(a.FaxNumber);
                    if (a.OriginalString == null) data.Add("");
                    else data.Add(a.OriginalString);
                }
```

It throws me a null exception if is some of elements in xml file missing - I dont wanna get this exception - I would like just add empty string beside missing element

Comment: As an aside, you can use the less verbose `data.Add( a.FaxNumer ?? "")` instead of all those if/elses.  Look up the null coalescing operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your Linq to XML query:

```
select new
{ 
  name = dataManufaturer.name ?? "",
  cageCode = dataManufaturer.cageCode ?? "",
  FaxNumber  = dataManufaturer.FaxNumber  ?? "",
  OriginalString = dataManufaturer.URL!=null ?  dataManufaturer.URL.OriginalString : ""
};
```

Comment: @the_drow: Well, I would use String.Empty as well purely out of convention, but they do point to the same empty string instance as `""` is interned.  There is no functional difference, so I am interested in why you seem to care so much.

Comment: @EdS.: Just a coding convention. Resharper recommends this as well. I would not kill anyone if I saw him using "" :)

Comment: @the_drow: Yeah, same here.  If I am working on a project where they use "" I will happily do so as well.

Comment: @the_drow: To add to that, in the early days of .NET there *was* a difference because the empty string was not interned, but that has not been the case for some time now.

Comment: @EdS.: What do you mean by not interned?

Comment: Sorry, but it doesnt work as I like to. For example I have only name element and other not - but I want to put to list all 4 elements - where is no element, there I would like to put ""

Comment: @Martin: what part doesn't work? Also what does the object (`Manufacturer`) that you are querying look like? This doesn't seem to be a Linq to XML, but a Linq to objects query.

Comment: When I have all elements in xml - it works fine, but If there are some missing - for example Fax number - in the list - data - is only one string "" - nothing else, but I need to have 4 entry in list

Comment: @Martin: you are not showing your Linq to XML query in your question, please update it.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: I dont do any Linq to XML - I just putting elements to List of strings - and this list I putting to table - there is no problem with Linq to XML - when I debug it and for example one element missing I have in this list only one string - ""

Comment: @BrokenGlass: To be more exact - it throws me a null exception - when is some element in xml missing