# linq query and nulls again

Tags: c#, xml, linq, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [linq query and nulls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164914/linq-query-and-nulls)

This throws a null exception if is some of elements in xml file missing - I don't want to get this exception - I would like just add empty string to list data beside missing element

```
InstrumentDescription inputFile = InstrumentDescription.Load(openFileDialog1.FileName);    
var queryManufacturer = from dataManufaturer in 
                                  inputFile.Identification.Manufacturers.Manufacturer
                            select new
                            { 
                                dataManufaturer.name,
                                dataManufaturer.cageCode,
                                dataManufaturer.FaxNumber,
                                dataManufaturer.URL.OriginalString
                            };


    foreach (var a in queryManufacturer)
    {
        data.Add(a.name);
        if (a.cageCode == null) data.Add("");
        else data.Add(a.cageCode);
        if (a.FaxNumber == null) data.Add("");
        else data.Add(a.FaxNumber);
        if (a.OriginalString == null) data.Add("");
        else data.Add(a.OriginalString);
    }
```

I tried somenthing like this - but it doesn't work

```
select new
{ 
  name = dataManufaturer.name ?? "",
  cageCode = dataManufaturer.cageCode ?? "",
  FaxNumber  = dataManufaturer.FaxNumber  ?? "",
  OriginalString = dataManufaturer.URL!=null ?  dataManufaturer.URL.OriginalString : ""
};
```

I want to have a empty string if some of elements are missing, not to get exception.

---

I SOLVE IT !!!

In select I only use `select new { dataManufacturer }`  not these all possible elements and when I am adding to list just test if for example dataManufacturer.name is null or not

Comment: It's not at all clear where XML comes into this, nor exactly where the NullReferenceException occurs. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Xml - I have a XSD scheme translated to code - in code I call just Load - I works fine, when I have all elements in reading file, but when there are at least one missing, it throw exception after select -add nothing to list

Comment: The only thing i can see causing that would be if the URL in `dataManufaturer.URL.OriginalString` is null. But you say it didint work when you added that if statement to the select? did you get the same error or something else? unless the whole dataManufaturer is null..

Comment: it throw NullReferenceException - if there is for example faxNumber - null

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post this "comment" here as a CW to help give you a nudge in the right direction in finding the source of the problem.

There are way too many potential causes for where the null reference exception will happen here in this block of code alone.  Looking at your responses in your other question, it's clear you have no idea how to find out where the problem is.  So try this to find out.  This is a rewritten form of the code you have shown us to facilitate finding out where the null is.  Run it to find out where this happens and hopefully you'll be able to fix it yourself.  If not, then ***please*** share the results of this test with us so we can better understand your problem and give you a better answer to help you fix your problem.

This assumes you are making a Windows Forms application or WPF application.

```
var dialog = openFileDialog1;
if (dialog == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("openFileDialog1 is null");
}
var filename = dialog.FileName;
if (filename == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("openFileDialog1.FileName is null");
}
InstrumentDescription input;
try
{
    input = InstrumentDescription.Load(filename);
}
catch (NullReferenceException e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("NullReferenceException in InstrumentDescription.Load():\n" + e.Message);
}
if (input == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("inputFile is null");
}
var id = input.Identification;
if (id == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("inputFile.Identification is null");
}
var mans = id.Manufacturers;
if (mans == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("inputFile.Identification.Manufacturers is null");
}
var man = mans.Manufacturer;
if (man == null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("inputFile.Identification.Manufacturers.Manufacturer is null");
}
var i = 0L;
foreach (var dm in man)
{
    if (dm == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("dataManufaturer at index "+i+" is null");
    }

    if (dm.name == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("dataManufaturer.name at index " + i + " is null");
    }
    if (dm.cageCode == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("dataManufaturer.cageCode at index " + i + " is null");
    }
    if (dm.FaxNumber == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("dataManufaturer.FaxNumber at index " + i + " is null");
    }
    var u = dm.URL;
    if (u == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("dataManufaturer.URL at index " + i + " is null");
    }
    if (u.OriginalString == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("dataManufaturer.URL.OriginalString at index " + i + " is null");
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I know, where is problem - I know how to debug and see all variables and everything step by step so I thing, that adding messagebox is not very comfort, also as I wrote in comment, I finally solve it, very simple, but thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var queryManufacturer = from dataManufaturer in input.Identification.Manufacturers.Manufacturer
where dataManufaturer != null
select {...}
```

Comment: no, dataManufacturer is never null - just some of this elements could be null